# How do I distribute free copies of a paid iOS app?

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me how I can give my paid app a free download option to one of my friend from iTunes Connect. What I mean is that I will give my friend a code by which he can download my app without paying. Can anyone tell me if there is any option in iTunes Connect to do this?

Comment: Give your question a meaningful title, please.

Answer (score 8):

Go to itunes Connect. Click on your app. Click on the current version. Click the *promo codes* button to download codes.

Send the code to your friend and they can redeem the app for free on iTunes.